# How to write data to a binary file using Python

Tags: python, file, hex, binaryfiles

I'm building an assembler for a Java-like bytecode. Essentially, it is a Python function which takes in a string, which was read from a text file containing opcodes, and writes the compiled binary data to a file. Here is an example of an input string string (from `Example.txt`):

```
class Example

Method add

meta
lva 4

code
0: ipush 1 0
1: ipush 2 2
2: iload 1
3: iload 2
4: iadd
5: istore 3
6: iload 3
7: ireturn
```

My task is to convert the `Example.txt` text file into it's binary representation (machine code for my virtual machine). Each opcode (e.g. `iadd`) is exactly one byte long (i.e. a number in the range of 0 to 255). Some opcodes take in operands, which are one byte long too.

Saving only the method's opcodes in a binary file is pretty easy. I'd parse each opcode into a number in the range of 0 to 255, and use `array.append(op)`, and then `array.tofile(handle)`.

However, I need to save not only the opcodes, but data, such as the name of the class, name of the method, etc.

**How can I save both one-byte values and more complex data to a binary file?**

I have envisioned something like this...

The file is divided into sections. The first section, for example, would be `class Example`. The next section is the one started by `Method add`.

Essentially, there are only two types of sections, the name section, which only contains `class name`, and the method section, which is then subsectioned into the meta and code sections.

Name sections start with `00` (in hex), and then need to present the name of the class (**this is my problem**). That `00` is essentially the hex representation of `class`. Method sections start with `FF`, and then they too, need to present their name in the next few bytes. Then, I could have `0F` to mean "start of meta section" and `F0` "start of code section" inside the primary Method section.

However, a problem remains. How do I name these sections? I had an idea of converting each character in e.g. "Example" to its hex representation, a single byte, and then saving those in the file after `00` or `FF`. This probably means that I will need some "end of section" symbol.

Is there a better/simpler/already implemented way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking a pretty sprawling question about design as well as basic Python usage.  I'm not sure you'll get a good answer until you limit the question a bit.

But let's focus on the question of how to convert a string, e.g. "Example", into an array of integers, so that you can append it to your `array`. Be sure you have a byte string; if you have a string of Unicode characters, be sure to encode it into an array of bytes first. (If you are using Python 2.x, your `string` is already an array of bytes.)

```
out = [0]  # your output array

s = "Example" # a byte string, not a Unicode string
l = list(s)   # convert to array of ints

out = out + l
print out
```

gives:

```
[0, 'E', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```